# Automatically load remote files in vim using netrw

Tags: vim, automation, netrw

I use vim and its netrw plugin to edit remote files too often. Many times, I had to close the current session and start a complete new session again later. But loading all those files (a lot of them) takes a lot of time and involvement (since I need to go to different dir and load those files one-by-one manually).

I need help to automate the file-loading process in the netrw.
I tried to do it myself using `execute` and `normal!` but there seems to be some problem (as the search operation like `execute 'normal! /root'` does not seem to work).

I tried using `<CR>` and it gives me `Trailing characters` error.

I know the absolute path of the files that I want to load. How can I automate the file-loading process ?

Comment: Can't you just load everything you want, then `:mksession my_remote_session.vim`?

Comment: I did, and that works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already used the right term in your question: *sessions* can help with that. You create one via `:mksession`; this basically generates a Vim script that, when executed (via `:source Session.vim`) in a new Vim instance, will restore all current buffers. This also works with *netrw*'s remote buffers - I only had to reload via `:e!` to fetch the contents again.

Note: There are plugins that further simplify session handling; I can recommend the [vim-session](https://github.com/xolox/vim-session) plugin.

Comment: Cool ! that works like a charm ! Thanks, I should have thought that ...

Comment: Glad I could help. I had never used netrw buffers in sessions; also had to try that out myself.

Comment: Any idea why I was not able to use `execute 'normal! /root'` like things ? or about `<CR>` giving trailing characters error ?